# Dateutil package resulting in script crashing

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I'm running a python script that utilizes the following package

`from dateutil.parser import parse`

The Library includes the following

```
    """This will take any date string and format into the date format you want    

    Args:
        date_str (string): Any date string 
        format (string): format you want 
        
    Example:    
        >>> my_date_format = format_date("2020-10-03", "%m/%d/%Y")
        >>> my_date_format = format_date("2020/10/03", "%m/%d/%Y")
        >>> my_date_format = format_date("10/03/2020", "%m-%d-%Y")
        >>> my_date_format = format_date("2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860", "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")
        >>> my_date_format = format_date("10/06/2020 at 7:40AM", "%b %d %Y at %I:%M%p")        
    """
    dt = parse(date_str)
    return dt.strftime(format)
```

However when I run anything that utilizes the above, I get the following error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File C:\Users\main\box\scripts\tests>python ra.py", line 26, in <module>
    from UtilLib import CodeStore, check_if_file_exists, getRandomUserInfo
  File "..\UtilLib.py", line 19, in <module>
    from dateutil.parser import parse
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 158
    l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

The error seems to be associated with the dateutil package that was installed. I can't figure out how to fix this. Where do I start?
````

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a version of the dateutil package that is meant to be used with Python 2, where backticks were used as a wrapper for `repr`, but you are using Python 3.

Run `pip install -U python-dateutil` (or whichever tool you are using as a package/dependency manager) to upgrade to a version of dateutil that supports the version of Python you are using.

Comment: I tried this, however it returned ```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dateutil (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dateutil``` I then tried to uninstall the package completely and it says `WARNING: Skipping dateutil as it is not installed.` but when I go back to reinstall it I get `Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (1.4)`. Is there a way to manually remove it?

Comment: The package is actually called `python-dateutil` on PyPI. I've edited DeepSpace's answer to reflect this. Not sure where you are getting the bad package, though, that might represent a deeper problem.